# Pointing Template Engine to Project Templates Directory

Tags: django, django-templates

I'd like to store templates that all app templates will extend from.

Current layout of project

```
mysite/ 
  -(virtualenv folders...)
  - wesdrew/ # project root
    - static/
    - templates/
      - base.html  # simple templates to test loading 
    - wesdrew/ # 'home page' app
```

In wesdrew/settings.py:

```
PROJECT_TEMPLATES='../templates'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [PROJECT_TEMPLATES],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Is there a way to override the template engine looking for '/templates/wesdrew'

Comment: are you trying to make the template engine look for your main `templates` folder in your project root?

Comment: Yes. I want the template engine to check there before checking app template folders.

Comment: I think you can remove the relative path `..` in front of your templates and just use `'templates'`. so `'DIRS': ['templates']`

Comment: Found the bug. It was in wesdrew/views.py.